# Trying to solve the pancakes problem in Prolog, having trouble unifying predicates

Tags: prolog, predicate

What I am trying to do is reverse the contents of a list from a specific member and onwards. Example [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], lets say I want to flip at 4, then it must become [1,2,3,7,6,5,4]. I wrote a "cut" predicate that returns [4,5,6,7] and from there on I use append/reverse to make the final list. If I write my predicates directly into TKeclipse, the result is exactly what I want. When I try to unify them in one "flip" predicate, then eclipse chadly responds with "No" and I can't figure out why.

```
cut([H|T], H, [H|T]).
cut([H|T], X, RightSublist):-
    X \= H,
    cut(T, X, RightSublist).

flip(state1, N, state2):-
    cut(state1, N, RightSublist),
    append(LeftSublist, RightSublist, state1),
    reverse(RightSublist, ReversedRightSublist),
    append(LeftSublist, ReversedRightSublist, state2).
```

Comment: Use `State1` instead of `state1` and `State2` instead of `state2`. Variables start with an upper case letter.

Comment: jesus im new to prolog but that was stupid even for a beginner, thank you very much for answering it took me nearly 40 minutes to spot this

Comment: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. `trace.` - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Answer (score 0):

This is a more efficient method, due to traversing the lists once, rather than using `append`:

```
flip_at_elem(Elem, Lst, Flip) :-
    flip_at_elem_(Lst, Elem, Flip, After, Rem),
    reverse(After, Rem).

flip_at_elem_([H|T], Elem, Flip, After, Rem) :-
    (   H = Elem
    ->  After = [H|T],
        Flip = Rem
    ;   Flip = [H|Flip0],
        flip_at_elem_(T, Elem, Flip0, After, Rem)
    ).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(flip_at_elem(4, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], F)).
% 11 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (80% CPU, 1133086 Lips)
F = [1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4].
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
flip_at(Xs,E,Ys) :- partition(Xs,Ys,E,RemX,RemY) , reverse(RemX,RemY) .

partition( [X|Xs] ,    Ys  , X , [X|Xs] , Ys   ) .
partition( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] , E , RemX   , RemY ) :- partition(Xs,Ys,E,RemX,RemY) .
```

Results (SWI Prolog):

```
?- time( flip_at( [a,b,c,d,e,f,g], d, Flipped ) ) .

10 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (103% CPU, 37321 Lips)

Flipped = [a, b, c, g, f, e, d]
```

Also, if you were going to use `append/3`, all you have to do is:

1. Partition the source list into its left and right halves.
2. Reverse the right half.
3. Append the left and reversed right halves, yielding the results.

We can partition the list easily enough:

```
partition( []     , _ , [] , []     ) .  % empty list or element not found
partition( [X|Xs] , X , [] , [X|Xs] ) .  % found the element, it and the remainder of the source list comprise the right half
partition( [X|Xs] , E , [X|Ys] , Zs ) :- % otherwise, add the head to the left half, if...
  X \= E,                                - it's not the element we're looking for, and
  partition(Xs,E,Ys,Zs).                 - recurse down
```

And once you have that...

```
flip( Xs , N , Ys ) :-
    partition(Xs,N,Ls,Rs),
    reverse(Rs,R0),
    append(Ls,R0,Ys) .
```